# dbt: vars in dbt_modules not recognized

Tags: dbt

For an unknown reason, the declared vars in the packages within the dbt_modules are not recognized anymore and need to be declared in the dbt_project.yml of the entire project vs. being declared only within the dbt_project.yml of the module.

When trying to preview the results of a staging model using one of the vars declared in the dbt_project.yml within the installed module, I get the following error:

```
Required var 'google_ads__click_performance' not found in config:
Vars supplied to request = {
"ad_reporting__facebook_ads_enabled": true,
"ad_reporting__google_ads_enabled": true,
"ad_reporting__linkedin_ads_enabled": true,
"ad_reporting__microsoft_ads_enabled": false,
"ad_reporting__pinterest_enabled": false,
"ad_reporting__snapchat_ads_enabled": false,
"ad_reporting__twitter_ads_enabled": false
}

> in rpc request (from remote system)
> called by rpc request (from remote system)
```

It used to recognize the vars declared within the module without having to declare them in the main dbt_project.yml file.

Could you please advise? This happened after I moved from dbt cloud 0.20.1 to 0.20.2

Thanks for your help

Comment: does this not happen if you downgrade back to `0.20.1`?

Comment: It seems like I can't go back to the previous version on dbt cloud, it has been deprecated and is not available as an option anymore.

Are you able to use vars in installed modules defined in their own dbt_project.yml file?

Thanks!